# Nested boolean operators in pandas

Tags: python, boolean

I'm trying to create and apply a function to group some data together based on the stemmed version of the words in a given cell.

Here's my relevant code:

```
    if "fee" in match and (
        "accredit" or
        "admin" or
        "administr" or
        "design" or
        "invest" or
        "one-tim") in match:
        return "Add-on fees"
```

For some reason I'm struggling to understand, this code is under-inclusive and only yields cells that have the values "fee" *and* "accredit" rather than "fee" and any of the others.

If I remove the first `in match` and just have the code as

```
    if "fee" and (
        "accredit" or
        "admin" or
        "administr" or
        "design" or
        "invest" or
        "one-tim") in match:
        return "Add-on fees"
```

It only gives me results that include "accredit" regardless of whether they contain "fee."

Everything I've been able to search about how to nest logical operators is more concerned with bitwise operators rather than Boolean.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

that is not how `and` and `or` work, they work more like

```
#X and Y
def and(X,Y):
    if bool(X):
        return Y
    else:
        return X

# X or Y
def or(X,Y):
    if bool(X):
        return X
    else:
        return Y
```

what you want is

```
if "fee" in match and any(word in match for word in ("accredit", "admin", "administr", "design", "invest", "one-tim")):
    return "Add-on fees"
```

Answer (score 0):

Avoid using `or` with strings unless you're sure what is going on. In your example `"accredit" or "admin" or "administr" or "design" or "invest" or "one-tim"` will always evaluate to `'accredit'`. Essentially, you're checking `"fee" in match and "accredit" in match`. Try something like:

```
arr = ["accredit", "admin", "administr", "design", "invest", "one-tim"]
match = ["fee", "design"]
("fee" in match) and any(x in match for x in arr)
# True
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem you're finding is that the words in the brackets are evaluating to whichever the first one is.

To make your code more readable, I would change it to the following:

```
if ("fee" in match) and do_other_checks(match):
    return "Add-on fee"

def do_other_checks(match):
    for word in [
        'accredit',
        'admin',
        'administr',
        'design',
        'invest',
        'one-tim',
    ]:
        if word in match:
            return True
    return False
```